# Weird silverlight cross domain service call problem

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight

So I have a Silverlight Lab that i downloaded from silverlight.net (it's part of the firestarter labs -- lab 10).

On my work machine, When I try to run it, I get the "cross-domain service call" exception.  Sort of makes sense, except that I do have a ClientAccessPolicy.xml file.

Now for the weird part:  If I enable Fiddler, the problem goes away, and my Silverlight app works!

Turn Fiddler off, and it fails again.

This seems to have something to do with the Proxy settings in Internet Explorer.  If I disable my proxy settings, I can also get the Silverlight app to work (but I can't browse the internet, of course).

Even weirder:
If I create my own Silverlight app "from scratch" and I use the same structure (separate Web Applications for the Silverlight host and the services), everything works, with no hiccups (and no need to fiddle with proxies).

Any idea what could cause that?

Comment: I think that it is because of a proxy server, you should write your credentials before method calls and configure config.

Comment: @vorrtex  I thought so too, but 2 things don't add up:  1.  I don't have any problems if I create a new app with the same structure.  2.  Our "main" proxy is an authenticated proxy, so I follow you on the proxy credentials.  However, we also have an unauthenticated proxy that I can kick over to.  I still get errors on the unauthenticated proxy.

Comment: Ok, my suggestion is to put a service and an application in the same web-application, and I'm sure that there won't be a cross-domain issues.

Comment: I have the same problem. The silverlight app requests crossdomain.xml mosts of the times, but for some users, it doesn't.